# Lorentz Four-force in General relativity?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, forces

In special relativity, it's normal to define Lorentz four-force density as $$f_\mu = F_{\mu\nu}\nabla _\lambda F^{\nu \lambda},$$
having Maxwell EM tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$. Can we do it in General relativity? Does "force" even have a meaning?

Comment: Related [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force#In_general_relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force#In_general_relativity)

Comment: The expression does not seem to have the right units (force/volumen)

Answer (score 1):

It should be valid applying the equivalence principle: , --> ;

Meaning every regular derivative becomes a covariant derivative.. so that ∆ should be uses with the correspondinh Christoffel symbols.